# Jquery audio position control

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery based MP3 player. To control audio I have this code:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"/>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(".audio-clip input[type='range']").on("input", function() {
    $(this).parent("div").find("audio")[0].volume = this.value;
  });
});
```

I wonder how can I do the same but for controlling the audio position with a `range` element in an MP3 song?

Comment: Can you not just use the standard controls of the `audio` element?

Comment: Try changing the event from "input" to "change".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you cannot use the standard `controls` attribute to handle volume and scanning through the file, you can use similar logic to what you have already implemented for volume to control the position in the file.

You can use a `range` element with values from `0` to `100` then set the `currentTime` of the audio, based on the value as a percentage. Also note that you can use the `timeUpdate` event to move the range slider along as the file plays. Try this:

```html
<div class="audio-clip">
  <audio id="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

  <label>
    Volume:
    <input type="range" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Position:
    <input type="range" class="position" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
  </label>
</div>
```

```js
$(".audio-clip .volume").on("input", function() {
  var audio = $(this).closest("div").find("audio")[0];
  audio.volume = this.value;
});

$('.audio-clip .position').on('input', function() {
  var audio = $(this).closest("div").find("audio")[0];
  audio.currentTime = (audio.duration / 100) * this.value;
});

$('audio').on('timeupdate', function() {
  var pc = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
  $(this).closest('div').find('.position').val(pc);
})
```

Note that the example won't work in a snippet due to the cross-domain audio source, however it does work in a fiddle as you can see in the link below:

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/25r8xaz4/)